# How to add cloud cover which is an image property as a band in the image collection using GEE Python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I am looking for percentage of cloud cover in my study region from landsat images. Here is the code I have got so far:

```
    def cloudcover(image):
        value = image.get("CLOUD_COVER_LAND")
        return image.addBands(value)

    collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2') \
    .map(cloudcover) \
    .select("CLOUD_COVER_LAND") \
    .filterBounds(polygon)
    
    listOfPoints = ee.FeatureCollection(points)
    col_med = collection.median()
    #extract values
    geemap.extract_values_to_points(listOfPoints, col_med, out_csv, scale= 30, crs = 'EPSG:4326')
```

But I keep getting this error:

EEException: reduce.median: Error in map(ID=LC08_166053_20180115):
Image.addBands: Parameter 'srcImg' is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically explicitly renaming the value to a completely different string other than the original name and defining the data type helped

```
    def cloudscore (image):
        value = image.getNumber("CLOUD_COVER_LAND")
        new_value = ee.Image(value).toDouble().rename('clouds')
        return image.addBands(new_value)
```

Answer (score 1):

When getting properties from an image of feature you typically have to cast it to the correct type before using it, or get it as the expected type directly:

`value = image.getNumber("CLOUD_COVER_LAND")`

or

`value = ee.Number(image.get("CLOUD_COVER_LAND"))`

Comment: After applying the suggestions, I get following error: 
EEException: reduce.median: Error in map(ID=LC08_166053_20180115):
Image.select: Pattern 'CLOUD_COVER_LAND' did not match any bands.

Comment: Explicitly turn the cloud cover to an image and rename it: `ee.Image(image.getNumber("CLOUD_COVER_LAND")).rename('CLOUD_COVER_LAND')`

Comment: I get this error: 
EEException: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with an incompatible band was encountered. Mismatched type for band 'CLOUD_COVER_LAND'. This band might require an explicit cast.

But as you also pointed out, I think explicitly renaming and defining the data type is the main cause of error. So, I modified your suggestion into following and no longer get the error:
    
    value = image.getNumber("CLOUD_COVER_LAND")
and 
    new_value = ee.Image(value).toDouble().rename('clouds')